# How can I access the value in a slot in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, slot

I want to format a string passed to a slot. Therefore, I need to access (read, write )the string with JavaScript. I went through the Vue.js documentation but did not figure out how access a string inside a slot.

I want to write

```
<format>12345</format>
```

and I want to format it to something like

```
12 3 45
```

How to format the string is not the problem. The problem is to access it.

The component is going to be used multiple time on one site.

Comment: Have you looked into sending it as a `prop`, and make a `computed` which you're using to format and show the output?

Comment: Yes, I know I can send it as a prop, but I would like to do it the way asked in the question. Writing “<format number="12345"></format>” is not as nice as “<format>12345</format>”

Comment: You can access slot data with `this.$slots`. If the data is not available there you will very likely need to wrap the string into a component, let's say `<data>12345</data>`, so that you will get the HTML element. After that it is only matter of doing `element.innerHTML` to get/set the data.

Comment: OK, I can access the data with `this.$slots`. But doing `element.innerHTML` does only set the data for the first component, the others are left empty, because the ID of all component instances are the same. Setting `this.$slots` has no effect.

Comment: I can write the data via a property. Now it works like I want. :) Thanks for the help.